# Why is Cassandra so slow with a composite partition key?

Tags: python, apache-spark, cassandra, pyspark

This is the issue that I am dealing with:

I have this 33 GB tsv file that has 2 columns, the first one is the a_id and the second one is a comma separated set of b_id's. The thing is, I need to be able to retrieve all a_id's for a b_id, so I load the file into Spark, I parse it, I flat map it and I insert that into a Cassandra table that is partitioned by b_id. The process takes about 4 hours, at 10~15 minutes per partition and loads all 200 M a_id's with an average of 20 b_id's each, so around 4 B rows total.

Issue is, because some of the b_id's are very common, some of these partitions are very large, the largest has 1.7 million cells. So I tried calculating a hash on the a_id and adding an new column to the table I was using (I actually created a new separate table), transitioning to a composite partition key. The result was a 6x increase in the time it takes to write each partition!!

At first, I thought that the issue was on the hash calculation that I was doing in Spark through the python hash() built-in, so I replaced that with a more naive function that would just modulo the last 20 bits of the a_id by the number of "subpartitions" that I want (5), but nothing changed...

I am not an expert in Cassandra by any means, but to me this doesn't make any sense. Why would this happen?

Comment: What?! Python `hash` for storing into database, man, that is **really wrong**. `hash` is guaranteed to be constant only during one interpreter execution.

Comment: ok, duly noted, I'll have to change that

Comment: Are you sure you used a composite partition key and not a clustering key?

Comment: yes, my create table statement looked something like "CREATE TABLE hashed_table (a_id text, b_id text, hash int, PRIMARY KEY ((b_id, hash), a_id))"

Comment: can you give a sample row as in how a_id and b_id looks ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure without seeing your PySpark code, but I suspect the slowdown is because you're manipulating the data using Python functions that can't be "pushed down" and done in the Spark Worker's JVM.

When you were just doing a simple flat map (I assume on an RDD using the Spark APIs for them), Spark was able to do that function inside the JVM. But once you start doing "custom" stuff in Python outside of those APIs, Spark has to serialize and stream your data between the Spark worker JVM and Python so it can run your Python code to manipulate the data. I believe it does this over a socket which is going to be slow. You can see more about the internals of PySpark here:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SPARK/PySpark+Internals